# Battery Monitoring Card Negative Voltage Measurement

Tags: batteries, integrated-circuit, battery-charging, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

I'm struggling to understand the working principle of these negative voltage measurement circuits. They are part of the battery monitoring card.

Schematic:

[image]

Upper schematics belongs to NXP RD9Z1-638BJBEVM Card (Based MM9Z1_638 ), other NXP RD33772BJBEVM Card (Based S32K144-MC33772).

Simulation Setup:

[image]

After activating PA1(or GPIO_OPTO1), the negative voltage is measured through VSENSE3(or  GPIO4)

When I am simulate circuits with LTspice (taking into account component part power ratings ), **I got similar values for both circuits. But these measured values are not within the specified pin nominal range of that datasheet.** (For the second circuit)**I also measured the huge power consumption of some 0402 package resistors**. Where am I wrong? How should I make sense of these measurements?

Ltspice measured values; Rds-on: OptoMOS(AQV258HAX) resistance when conduction occurs(from datasheet,for 600V load)

[image]

RD33772BJBEVM https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM11328.pdf

RD9Z1-638BJBEVM https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM11396.pdf

Comment: Your question is hard to follow with excessive resolution is the data. Pls make the specs clear and define expected and actual with limits in a concise table with tolerances on parts. Also don't use 6 sigfigs. and always derate power limits by at least 1/3. for reliability.  You don't want parts at 100'C above room temp.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I reorganized the problem explanation.

Comment: Your schematic is incomplete and fairly useless as it stands now. Try and think about the person reading this and not how you imagine it presents itself. How would anyone know what node 009 is and node 004 is and how they relate to your LTSpice diagrams? How do these relate to anything at all?

Comment: @Andyaka I put the related labels on the simulation picture

Comment: USe a table with consistent node refs and design target and actual result errors with tolerances permitted. Then describe  purpose of monitor for gain, offset and if cell balancing is planned. A tolerance stackup is necessary to calculate.

Comment: Perhaps a block diagram is necessary  to show all voltage sources and Vref. Even though it looks like a simpleKVL  problem, it isn't , as it stands